# An answer that I gave 8 years ago was suddenly "hidden." Why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

My reputation was reduced by 8 and I went to check why, and this message appeared:
"This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted via review 11 hours ago by Jhorra, Mathieu, manuell, Wiktor Stribiżew."

[Lightweight C/C++ GUI Library with Native Look & Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869849/lightweight-c-c-gui-library-with-native-look-feel/4869907#4869907)

What's going on? How can I find out why my answer was deleted?

Comment: Your answer ended up in the [Low Quality Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24822605), deleted by four reviewers who felt that it was not an explicit answer.  And really, it wasn't; it was a comment at best.  Your post was `"If you think about what you're asking, you're asking a lot. To do this, the windowing/GUI APIs must be abstracted to a common point across all supported platforms. That is a very large and complex task."`  Honestly, I would have deleted it too, or flagged it to be turned into a comment.

Comment: It's an answer. It shouldn't have been deleted.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - Well, the whole question is off-topic, and it's been closed, so I presume that the the "answer" will go away with all of the others once it's been community-deleted.  And, as usual, we disagree.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If we follow your reasoning then we should not delete anything.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I think the logic is that the post was actually an answer, therefore should not have been deleted through review.  Not that no answer can ever be deleted, but that the review was incorrect.

Comment: @fbueckert I guess. But one of the predefined delete reasons is "...This should have been a comment..." and that particular answer falls into that category. It is not real full fledged answer, it is more of a comment.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I'd agree.  But people are allowed to have differing opinions.  NAA has enough grey area that there's some room for interpretation.

Comment: @fbueckert Yep, plenty of gray there. I was just disagreeing with the opinion that it should not have been deleted. Nothing more :)

Comment: For anyone wondering why today:  A new user posted an answer to it.  Presumably one of the reviewers gave everything else a once over while there.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The question was "What should I use to do X?"; the answer the OP gave was, "X is really hard, you shouldn't do it that way."  That's an answer to the question.  "Don't do X" is always an answer -- in this case it was the question that was out of bounds.  So to focus on the answer is to ignore the most problematic part -- the question!

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks for the explanation... I can follow that logic... but  I am not only focusing on answer here. In theory if question would be on topic and answer would be along the lines "don't do X", then I would not be in favor of deleting such answer.

Comment: My specific question had more to do with finding information about the deletion, not whether it was proper to delete in the first place. So how do I navigate to, and find any particular post in, the "Low Quality Review Queue"?

Comment: Just as a side comment: the age of a contribution is not really relevant for the decision if it should be deleted or not.

Comment: @Trilarion With the exception of questions of historical significance, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697/whats-the-best-mock-framework-for-java.  If this question were recently asked, it would be deleted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find this information by going to [that posts timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4869907/timeline).

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/{answerid}/timeline
```

In there, you can click on the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24822605) that eventually lead to the posts deletion.

Comment: Geesh, how was I supposed to know sometime like that existed.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340118 - you're not alone, many agree that having an option to see the timeline would be useful

Comment: There is also `/revisions`, which you can see by manipulating the URL in the same way. (This is the same view you can access from a direct link when a post has been edited.) I like this better than the timeline because I think it’s easier to read.